# The Mysql query in PHP code doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, string, request, timestamp

Here is the code where I want to select only  `"tbl_name,itime_end,itime_start"` above a certain date in Timestamp:

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('
SELECT 
tbl_name,
itime_end,
itime_start 
FROM table_ref 
WHERE `itime_start` > ".$Timestamp_UserStartDate." 
')
```

`itime_start` and `$Timestamp_UserStartDate` are in Timestamp

but when I do a gettype, `$timestamp_USerStartDate` is an integer and `$itime_start` is a string.
An `echo $timestamp_USerStartDate;` gives : `1365408000`
and an `echo $donnees['itime_start'];` gives : `1364998028` ...

The result is that all the data selected are displayed without being filtered !
Thanks in advance for your advice !

Comment: Are you SURE that the single, double quotes and concatenation dots are in the correct order?

Comment: yeah that's it , tnx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you really shouldn't be injecting your variables the way that you're doing it. You should bind variable placeholders and then populate them later. However, the issue with your code is that you're not ending your single parenthesis the way that you're intending to. Try the line below

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT tbl_name,itime_end,itime_start FROM table_ref WHERE `itime_start` > "'.$Timestamp_UserStartDate.'" ')
```

Comment: And a semicolon at the end? ;)

Comment: the semicolon isn't necessary

Comment: @Bryan Moyles Do you know how can I put the results in the SELECT of a new query and display the result of this second query for each result of the first query ?

Comment: I would recommend either doing a subselect, or more preferably a JOIN. So in your query you can do SELECT * FROM (SELECT ....) t, please note that the ) t, was not a typo, the t, or some arbitrary character to alias the subselect is necessary

Answer (score 1):

If you looked at the query as it is produced, you'd see it is not what you intended.

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("
    SELECT 
        tbl_name,
        itime_end,
        itime_start 
    FROM table_ref 
    WHERE `itime_start` > " . $Timestamp_UserStartDate
);
```

will do what you expect, provided that `itime_start` and `$Timestamp_UserStartDate` both are UNIX timestamps.